# how to send a custom urls on facebook using multifriendselector

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, multi-friend-selector

i have this code

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<p>
<input type="button"
  onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
  value="Send Request to Many Users with MFS"
/>
</p>

<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '308928229202619',
    frictionlessRequests: true
  });


  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Invite user to play and you will get a chance to win.'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
      alert("this is the response");
      alert(response);
    // Handle callback here
  }
</script>
```

i want that on facebook this url will be send out when user send request e.g

```
  Send_url:
  http://www.abc.com/send_invite_by.php?code=abc OR
  http://www.abc.com/send_invite_by.php?code=zyx
```

Depend on auto generated id

and it will return on this URL

```
 return_url http://www.abc.com/recieved_invite.php?code=zyx
```

what i want that i want to know who send the invitation on this behaf i have to give user points on the invitation accepted.

Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i want that i want to know who send the invitation

You will get that info when you look up the request_id (which is passed to you when a user accepts a request) via the API – it has a `from` field that contains sender’s name and id.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#request_format for details.

Comment: this is what i am getting 

`http://www.abc.com/?request_ids=362592640499894%2C245446585583296%2C384763451605715%2C554959034531335%2C443684732334259%2C509615065724899%2C491473020873060&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&code=AQBzdfzIfBnFsh_AyhqRlKqG8_3Oc4F-xFkumoOOAhPgJaYgXjLpZ6WnzuBgW5AP4fCJX0wHIXarIC0rYymw99l1yJ2TpbErdTs7S-FoeA61FB4E_1YDhceglNL6bJOA8M6dKZ3mSMY9gkMvZvBUMZixRnQYW5sHRejcIAndxITo3eyz9agTmBq3NBubhZJmBNoQ-fp3eTbEV9lWTg7Sskfw#_=_`

Comment: Apart from that this URL should rather begin with `https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/` … OK.

Comment: am i doing the wrong API, i want to send invitations from users and when they will accept it the sender will get points? how i can send user my own URL? why i have to send the apps.facebook.com?

Comment: You DON’T have to “send your own URLs” (and you can’t, actually). Accepting a request will _always_ open the app canvas page. And there you’ll get the request ID(s), and can use them to look up who send them via the API.

Comment: Sorry i am new for that, i don't know what about it,do i have to set that URL string? will it be like `https://apps.facebook.com/308928229202619/` where i have to set it
and do i have to write more code in app? how this will work.

Comment: You only have to set your Canvas URL in your app settings – and when a user accepts a request, he will be automatically taken to Facebook, where your Canvas URL will get embedded in an iframe.

Comment: i have set the canvas URL, now do i have to use the graph API to get the user detail? that requires the access token?

Comment: Thanks, now on the facebook page i have to use the graph API to get who has sent the request, this is very cheep that Facebook has removed FBML and still providing the ways to do it.